# How to get a circle shape layer with one edge as a gradient and the other one as a full color

Tags: ios, swift

I have done this circle gradient layer:

[image]

What I would like to have is only one gradient (the one on the left) while the gradient on the bottom would be removed to show a clear separation between red and yellow.

As I will need to make an animation out of it (like a loading view), I thought about having an image in the background and having a circle shape layer with a color (like white) on top and change the stroke of this layer as I need.

Another solution I thought about was having tow circle shape layers, one with the gradient, the other one without.

But both those solutions feels more like a hack and I was wondering if there was a proper one using just

Here is the code I used:

```
fileprivate func createProgressLayer() {
    let startAngle = CGFloat(M_PI_2)
    let endAngle = CGFloat(M_PI * 2 + M_PI_2)
    let centerPoint = CGPoint(x: frame.width / 2 , y: frame.height / 2)

    progressLayer.path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter:centerPoint, radius: frame.width / 2 - 30.0, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: endAngle, clockwise: true).cgPath
    progressLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    progressLayer.fillColor = nil
    progressLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    progressLayer.lineWidth = 4.0
    progressLayer.strokeStart = 0.0
    progressLayer.strokeEnd = 1.0

    let gradientMaskLayer = gradientMask()
    gradientMaskLayer.mask = progressLayer
    layer.addSublayer(gradientMaskLayer)
}

fileprivate func gradientMask() -> CAGradientLayer {
    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.frame = bounds

    gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 0.1]
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0)

    let arrayOfColors: [AnyObject] = [UIColor.red.cgColor, UIColor.yellow.cgColor]
    gradientLayer.colors = arrayOfColors

    return gradientLayer
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Shape layers only support a single color.

In order to get the effect that you're after I think you're going to need to use a shape layer as a mask on your gradient like you're doing.

Having a second white shape layer on top of the gradient+mask layer and changing strokeStart and/or strokeEnd also sounds like a reasonable way to do what you're trying to do.

Doing tricks ("hacks" as you call them) with layers is quite common and a reasonable way to do what you're trying to do.